# Consulta muchos a muchos laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Bueno como ven estoy aprendiendo laravel, es por eso que necesito ayuda por los expertos de forma clara si no es mucha molestia para no perderme.

*'**Quiero recibir este arreglo en mi componente vue. y no me funciona con el foreach en la vista por que no es php**'*

Quiero obtener todos los datos relacionados de mi tabla **productos**  con la tabla **atributo_producto** para poder realizar mi vista de producto (listado o view)

[image: Esta es la imagen de mi relación atributo_producto]

en mi controlador **ProductoController** he generado lo siguiente,

```
          $productos = Producto::join('clases as c', 'productos.id_clase','=', 'c.id')
            ->join('grupos as g', 'productos.id_grupo', '=', 'g.id')
            ->select('productos.id as id',
                'productos.numero as numero',
                'productos.codigo as codigo',
                'productos.unidad-venta as unidad_venta',
                'productos.precio-unitario as precio_unitario',
                'productos.stock as stock',
                'productos.inventario as inventario',
                'productos.sujeto-retencion as sujeto_retencion',
                'productos.sujeto-impuesto as sujeto_impuesto',
                'productos.palabra-clave as palabra_clave',
                'g.nombre as grupo',
                'c.nombre as clase')
            ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(5);

    $rangos = array();
    foreach ($productos as $producto){
       $rangos[$producto->id] = Producto::find($producto->id)->rangos;
    }


    $atributos=array();
    $variable = array();
    foreach ($productos as $producto) {
        $variable[$producto->id] = Producto::find($producto->id);
        foreach($variable[$producto->id]->atributos as $varia){
            array_push($atributos, $varia);
        }
    }

    return[
        'pagination' => [
            'total'         => $productos->total(),
            'current-page'  => $productos->currentPage(),
            'per_page'      => $productos->perPage(),
            'last_page'     => $productos->lastPage(),
            'from'          => $productos->firstItem(),
            'to'            => $productos->lastItem()
        ],

        'productos'         => $productos,
        'rangos' => $rangos,
        'atributos' => $atributos
    ];
```

En la parte donde tengo mis dos foreach quisiera que me mostrara todas las relaciones de mi producto con su valor pivot. Pero solo me manda un solo registro 
[image: Esto es lo que me muestra en vez de toda la relacion]

a lo mejor mi lógica sea muy poca pero quisiera ayuda para poder realizar esta consulta

Nota: ya tengo mis dos modelos corresponidientes:

**Modelo Producto**

```
     public function atributos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Atributo', 'atributo_producto', 'id_atributo', 'id_producto')->withPivot('valor');
}
```

**Modelo Atributo**

```
    public function productos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Producto', 'atributo_producto', 'id_producto', 'id_atributo')->withPivot('valor');
}
```

Lo ando haciendo de esta manera por que quiero recibir el arreglo completo para poder obtenerlo en mi Componente Producto.vue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tus relaciones se encuentran incorrectas, deberían de quedar así:

```
public function atributos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Atributo', 'atributo_producto', 'id_producto', 'id_atributo')->withPivot('valor');
}

public function productos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Producto', 'atributo_producto', 'id_atributo', 'id_producto')->withPivot('valor');
}
```

Y para traer todos los productos con sus respectivos atributos solo bastaría hacer:

```
$productos = Producto::with('atributos')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(5);

foreach($productos as $producto){
   $nombres_atributos = array();
   $pivotes = array();

   //Para acceder a los atributos:
   foreach($producto->atributos as $atributo){
      $nombre_atributo = $atributo->nombre;
      //Para obtener el valor pivote
      $pivote = $atributo->pivot->valor;

      $pivotes[] = $pivote;
      $nombres_atributos[] = $nombre_atributo;
   }
}
```

Comment: Se te agradece  amigo la verdad es que me complique la vida yo solo